# BULK INSERT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert

On MS SQL, I can do bulk insert using the sql command below:

```
BULK INSERT myDatabase.MyTable FROM 'C:\MyTextFile.txt' WITH  FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
```

Now I want to do the same on MySQL but I can't seem to figure out how this works and what query to use.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In MySQL, the equivalent would be

LOAD DATA INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\MyTextFile'
INTO TABLE myDatabase.MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: How would you do the 'ignore', as if I have a number "2,123.23" How would I ignore that comma

Comment: Thank you, here is more detailed overview of this and one more option: https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723