# Method for inserting data with thread safety.. static or new class?

Tags: c#, mysql, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I want to use parallel for inserting data into MySQL.

```
Class Database
{
    ...

    public static void insert(string line)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO db." + line + " VALUES (..)";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBconnection))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my question.

```
Parallel.ForEach(List, value =>
{
    // HERE
});
```

Which code should I use?

```
Database.insert(something);
```

or

If I change *public static void insert* to *public void insert*

and use

```
new Database().insert(something);
```

Which code is thread safe and better? Is it the same thing?

Comment: You're better of with an `void Insert(IEnumerable<string> lines) {}`. Keep the connection open and use proper parameters.

Comment: Both are thread-safe from C# point of view (so let's go on with static method). Of course it may not be safe from SQL point of view (but this depends how your tables are and how you'll manage concurrency there). It may even be possible that you don't speed-up anything because each connection will lock until previous one finished inserting. That said to create a connection for such small task (insert) can be pretty expansive so overhead can be much higher than benefits (in this case).

Comment: If you have a large amount of data to insert in your database then I would go with a BULK INSERT. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql) for an example.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you! Can you give me a example code please?!

Comment: @Adriano Aha! borh are thread safe. What if the data is needed to insert into different tables?

Comment: Then your limit (to parallelism) is given by your DB server (how many parallel connections it can handle? how many parallel requests it can serve?). Anyway whenever possible you should reuse same connection (to create it can be pretty expansive). Do not make parallel insert() function but put your parallel loop to run multiple commands.