# Changing the order of columns in a CSV file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv

[image]I have a CSV files output from a software without headers,
I need to change the order of columns based on a config file

initial-column   Final-Column
   1                  5
   2                  3
   3                  1

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: read it in as 1-2-3-4-5 then write it out as 1 5 2 3 3 1

Comment: @Plutonix how do you do that, could you please give a code snippet.

Comment: what has you confused?  open a file, reading a file, parsing the data, writing it out?  So far this is just a write-my-codez-for me question.  One or 2 lines of the data would be nice to see as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very very little to go on, such as how the config file works and what the data looks like.

Note that using the layout of `{1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1}` you arent just reordering the columns,  that drops one (4) and duplicates columns 1 and 3.

Using some fake random data left over [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831064/1070452), this reads it in, then writes it back out in a a different order.  You will have to modify it to take the config file into consideration.

Sample data:

> Ndxn fegy n, 105, Imaypfrtzghkh, -1, red, 1501
>   Mfyze, 1301, Kob dlfqcqtkoccxwbd, 0, blue, 704
>   Xe fnzeifvpha, 328, Mnarhrlselxhcyby hq, -1, red, 1903

```
Dim csvFile As String = "C:\Temp\mysqlbatch.csv"
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile)

Dim outFile As String = "C:\Temp\mysqlbatch2.csv"
Dim data As String()

Dim format As String = "{0}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {0}"

Using fs As New StreamWriter(outFile, False)
    For Each s As String In lines
        ' not the best way to split a CSV,
        ' no OP data to know if it will work
        data = s.Split(","c)
        ' specifiy the columns to write in
        ' the order desired
        fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format,
                                   data(0),
                                   data(1),
                                   data(2),
                                   data(3),
                                   data(4),
                                   data(5)
                                 )
                    )
    Next
End Using
```

This approach uses the format string and placeholder (`{N}`) to control the order.  The placeholders and array elements are all zero based, so `{1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1}` becomes `{0, 4, 1, 2, 2, 0}`. Your config file contents could simply be a collection of these format strings.  Note that you can have more args to `String.Format()` than there are placeholders but not fewer.

Output:

> Ndxn fegy n,  red,  105,  Imaypfrtzghkh,  Imaypfrtzghkh, Ndxn fegy n
>   Mfyze,  blue,  1301,  Kob dlfqcqtkoccxwbd,  Kob dlfqcqtkoccxwbd, Mfyze
>   Xe fnzeifvpha,  red,  328,  Mnarhrlselxhcyby hq,  Mnarhrlselxhcyby hq, Xe fnzeifvpha

Splitting the incoming data on the comma (`s.Split(","c)`) will work in many cases, but not all.  If the *data* contains commas (as in some currencies "1,23") it will fail.  In this case the seperator char is usually ";" instead, but the data can have commons for other reasons ("Jan 22, 2016" or "garden hose, green"). The data may have to be split differently.

<sub>**Note:** All the OPs previous posts are `vba` related.  The title includes `VB.NET` and is tagged [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), so this is a VB.NET answer</sub>

Comment: Thank you for you help and patience ,I'm just starting out with coding.!

Comment: I wrote a function to read the text file and generate a string

`code  fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format, CReadConfig.ReadConfigsource(ConfigFilepath)))
`

the function returns this value

data(0),data(1),data(2),data(3)

the format string is :
{0},{1},{2},{3}

I'm getting an error:
Index(Zero based) must be greater than or equal to Zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: I have no idea exactly what is in the config file or how you processed it.  You *certainly* do not need to call the function in the loop.  `{0},{1},{2},{3}` looks legal, but it wont reorder the columns - note how that the placeholders are what control the output order.  You should ask a new question so you can show the config file contents and the method you have to read it and work out the order.