# Python: JSON to CSV (Billions of rows)

Tags: python, mysql, json, csv

In order to insert my data fast in MySQL, I have decided to take the 6200 JSON files I have (which have ~200K rows each) and convert them to CSV. Then, I want to use LOAD DATA INFILE to quickly insert all CSVs in MySQL. This is what I am doing so far:

```
myList = []
path = *some path to my files*
for filename inglob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.JSON')):
    with open(filename) as json_data:
        j = json.load(json_data)
        for i in j["rows"]:
            user_id = i["values"][0][0]
            birthday = int(float(i["values"][0][1])/1000)
            gender = str(epoch_timestamp)
            age = i["values"][0][2]
            eye_color = i["values"][0][3]
            data = (user_id, birthday, gender, age, eye_color)
            myList.append(data)

fn = '/Users/srayan/Desktop/myCSV.csv'
with open(fn,'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerows(myList)
```

My problem is, going through each, individual row out of 1 billion rows of JSON is very inefficient - is there any way that I can either grab row data from JSON without having to iterate every single row? Or is anyone aware of a faster method than going from JSON -> CSV -> LOAD INFILE to MySQL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql

Comment: @WEI_DBA I am planning on using LOAD DATA INFILE - but I am looking more for a solution on how to convert JSON to CSV fast

Comment: why its a billion row , its 200k row  is it? . why your combining , its a loop of 6200 !!

Comment: No, 200k row per JSON file. 6200 JSON files. If you do the math... 1.2 billion rows total.