# I want to parse and upload a large csv file into a msql database, but its taking forever. Python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

I'm trying to import a large CSV file (1gb) into a MySQL database using `csv.Dictreader()`, but it's taking way too long. Do you have any suggestions to make it parse and upload faster?

Here is an example of my code:

```py
def process_data(self):
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['data_file'].file, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in reader:
        Csv.objects.create(starttime=datetime.strptime(row["startTime"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                           incidents_id=(row['id']), type=(row['type']),
                           subtype=(row['subtype']), reportdescription=(row['reportDescription']),
                           street=(row['street']),
                           reportby=(row['reportBy']),
                           longitude=Decimal(row['longitude']), latitude=Decimal(row['Latitude']),
                           endtime=datetime.strptime(row["endTime"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), dataowner_id=1)
```

This is my Model

```
class Csv(models.Model):
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    subtype = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reportdescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    reportby = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    endtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    incidents_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    dataowner = models.ForeignKey('Dataowner', models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'csv'
```

Comment: I will recommend you to use pandas to sql ...here is a example .. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-insert-tutorial/  I mean read the csv file with pandas and then insert in your table

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your model structure, which keys, indexes and the file size are used, but I would recommend you take a look at bulk create ORM function which should improve performance.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

> **bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False)**
>
> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in
>   an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
>   objects there are):
>
> ```
> >>> Entry.objects.bulk_create([
> ...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
> ...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
> ... ])
> ```

Comment: i fixed the bulk_create to work, but the speed doesnt change its just as slow

Comment: how many lines are in the CSV? How long does it take to load the file into the DB?

Comment: My csv has 4 million rows. First secon is 800 rows. Second second is 800 rows. after that its 100 rows per second

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `LOAD DATA` functionality of MySQL and [bulk import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql) the CSV file to the database.

Comment: but the code is for use it with python ...how can you combine both ...python and bulk ?

Comment: No python needed at all as the data is already available as a CSV, except maybe for data cleaning if required.

Comment: In my csv some column values need to be changedto the correct datatype. Im not sure load data would work with that. If you have any ideas let me know please

Comment: As the slow part is writing to the database, most likely not working with Python or file operations, you could either correct the datatypes via Python before loading via LOAD statement (read CSV, correct types, write CSV, load to DB) or generate SQL statements which are used for a separate load step (MySQL CLI tools should provide that).